# scrolling the background image in android java while adding a view to screen

Tags: android, view, background, scroll

I want to `scroll` the background in android. I have a `scrollview` which has many views. I need to implement a way wherein i need to scroll *only* the background while adding the views. I came across many forums but none of them are very clear. Please give an idea or references to implement it. To give more idea for what i am looking for is, Just consider a bike game wherein the background road image moves while riding the bike. I just need similar implementation while scrolling the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do like this:

- `RelativeLayout` as the parent

  - `ScrollView` with your image set as background
- Then the other views, but outside of the `ScrollView` and inside of the `RelativeLayout`.

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relParent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

 <OtherViews />

 <ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrlParent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:background="@drawable/yourbackground">

  </ScrollView>     

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I think that something like this might work. You see, the `RelativeLayout` is the parent. Then comes your other views, on the top of your `ScrollView`. Then, after your other views tag, comes the `ScrollView`, with only a background. I'm not sure if a background tag would work, so  maybe you should remove the `android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"` and put an `ImageView` inside of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. But i could not understand "Then the other views, but outside of the ScrollView and inside of the RelativeLayout." Will you please explain a bit